# How to avoid a redirect chain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

SSL & SEO Report of my-website says:

**http://**my-website.com/ redirects to **https://www**.my-website.com/ through a redirect chain. This hurts your rankings

**http://**my-website.com/ --> **https://**my-website.com/  -->
 **https://www**.my-website.com/

How to avoid this redirect chain via .htaccess?

My actual htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What have you got in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: use Canonical URL

Comment: @Lag I have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

Change your `.htaccess` code to force HTTPs and WWW to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This combines your rules and will stop them from chaining. The first condition checks if HTTPs is not on and the second condition checks if `www` is present or not.

If either of those conditions fail, it will rewrite the URL using 301 redirection to use both HTTPs and `www`.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing it.